# Why is an AppTheme applied to the custom ActionBar toolbar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, themes, toolbar

I'm using Custom `Toolbar`. So I set `AppTheme`(BaseTheme) as `NoActionBar`.

I ran the app but Custom `Toolbar` still has `AppTheme`'s color.

I also changed `AppTheme`'s color in this state. By the way, The color of the toolbar has changed.

I don't know why this happens.

`AppTheme`set `NoActionbar` and I used to custom toolbar and I didn't set any Theme on the custom toolbar

But why is the Custom Toolbar affected by Base Theme?

this is code.

Manifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.writeweight">
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.WriteWeight">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/coordinator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:elevation="0dp">
            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:title="ㅅㅅㅅ"/>
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

values.themes.xml

```
<style name="Theme.WriteWeight" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>
```

THANK YOU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use it

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"/>
```

It will take the color ColorPrimary.

Custom Style

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Toolbar.Primary"
     />
```

Comment: So does the color of the toolbar change if I change the colorPrimary of Theme.WriteWeight regardless of what I set NoActionbar?

Comment: Here we take the corresponding color as attr. Source colors.xml. It is not clear what you want to ask. Although it is the NoActionBar I understand, the color value does not change.

Comment: Maybe it will help. https://guides.codepath.com/android/using-the-app-toolbar

Comment: ?attr/ references to attributes. Attributes are values specified in an app's theme. The attributes in your example are all values specified in the themes provided by the support library. Android also has its very own attributes which can be used with ?android:attr/.

Comment: attr. Source colors.xml? But when i changed primaryColor in values.themes.xml, Toolbar's color changed.. primaryColor exist in values.themes.xml..And Its Theme set NoActionBar. 
However I changed primaryColor in values.themes.xml, My custom toolbar's color also changed. But Custom Toolbar does not set Theme.
Why is primaryColor applied to the custom tool bar? Toolbar does not set Theme and Toolbar has nothing to do with primaryColor in Theme.WriteWeight?

Comment: Considering you want to add a custom style for MaterialToolbar. I updated the code. By default, the Toolbar requests the corresponding colors. That's why the color values ​​are adjusted this way.